# How to parse nested arrays inside json using C++

Tags: c++, json, boost

I know how to parse "normal" looking `JSON` data in `C++`. Usually, I do this, using `boost::property_tree` and `read_json` method. It may look like so:

```
BOOST_FOREAH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("rows"){
    vec.push_back(v.second.get<std::string>("key"));
}
```

and the code above corresponds to this JSON file:

```
{
    "rows":[{
         "key":"1"
     },{
         "key":"2"
     }]
}
```

However, the `Neo4j` result-set that I get, looks like:

```
{
    "columns":{...},
    "data":[[["object 1"]], [["object 2"]], [["object 3"]]]
}
```

I'm interested and want to parse `"data"` node. I tried to do it like so:

```
BOOST_FOREAH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("data"){
    vec.push_back(v.second.data());
}
```

but this does not work. I do not get an error, but my vector `vec` remains empty, or to be more precise it is populated with empty values. So, that when I iterate through this `vec` I see a number of elements, but they do not have any value. Whereas, I want to have values `"object 1"`, `"object 2"`, `"object 3"`.

Comment: https://github.com/jeaye/jeayeson, json_spirit, to name just two libraries that will do this.

Comment: These libraries look promissing, but are you 100% sure, that they will parse my json file?

Comment: @Jacobian If library claims that it supports parsing of standard JSON then it will parse standard JSON otherwise it is buggy. Or your question is not clear.

Comment: The answer is literally in the ~20 lines of documentation specific to the JSON backend. It's also a very frequently asked question here so a quick search of [tag:boost-propertytree] + `array` should give you helpful answers in seconds. I would like to conclude with my caveat that Boost doesn't come with a JSON or XML library. It does have a property tree library. People confusing the two are a very frequent occurrence and [SO] is littered with the wreckage of that.

Comment: Boost comes with json_parser

Comment: I've seen here at stackoverflow some possible solutions. But they require nesting of BOOST_FOREAH. And I find this too clunky.

Comment: What library contains said `json_parser`? Note it's actually just a namespace!  Unfortunately named. It contains helpers like `read_json`, among others. Now,  what is the documented purpose of said functions?  (A hint: it's still `boost::property_tree::read_json`)

Comment: Rest assured. I'm well aware of what JSON / XML capabilities Boost has. You'd have known this if you had read some of the existing answers I was trying to point to. This I was doing to help.

Comment: Thanks for help! If only the learing curve in `C++` was not so steep. In other languages it may take just a couple of minutes to impelemt this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution looks like this:

```
using boost::property::ptree;
ptree pt;
//... populate ptree pt with data from some source
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child('data')){
    ptree subtree1 = v.second;
    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &vs, subtree1){
        ptree subtree2 = vs.second;
        BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &vs2, subtree2){
            do_something(vs2.second.data());
        }
    }
}
```

This code makes it possible to parse such JSON structure:

```
{
 "data":[[["object 1"]], [["object 2"]], [["object 3"]]]
}
```

So, contrary to what some people are saying, actually, there is no need to use other third-party libraries. Use just `boost` and you are done.

Comment: Though, I do not like this code. I wish there was some sort of simplification. Since, copy pasting `BOOST_FOREACH` looks rather technical.

Comment: Indeed. There's often no *need* for third party libraries. Although you're just lucky this covers your needs. Good  luck if ever you need to format a proper JSON number. This is why is even worse to evangelise Boost Property Tree as a JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I do it.  You have to know the JSON structure ahead of time.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

boost::property_tree::ptree pt, sub_pt;
std::string json_str, key, sub_key;
std::stringstream ss;
int value = 0, bus_num = 0;

json_str = "{\"arduino_1\": {\"bus_1\": 17425,\"bus_2\": 1025,\"bus_3\": 0,\"bus_4\": 0,\"bus_5\": 0,\"bus_6\": 0,\"bus_7\": 0,\"bus_8\": 0}}";


ss << json_str; // put string into stringstream
boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);    // put stringstream into property tree
for (boost::property_tree::ptree::iterator iter = pt.begin(); iter != pt.end(); iter++)
{
    // get data
    key = boost::lexical_cast <std::string>(iter->first.data());
    sub_pt = iter->second;

    // iterate over subtree
    for (boost::property_tree::ptree::iterator sub_iter = sub_pt.begin(); sub_iter != sub_pt.end(); sub_iter++)
    {
        // get data
        sub_key = boost::lexical_cast <std::string>(sub_iter->first.data());
        value = boost::lexical_cast <int>(sub_iter->second.data());
    }
}
```